# Python3 from CSV moving every 5 duplicate values to new CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a large .csv with businesses, business contacts, and contact info. The issue I have is that many of the companies have 20-50 contacts and I'm wanting to have a max of 5 per CSV. Any recommendation as to how I could do this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: So you need only 5 business contacts, and contact info in one csv file is it ?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't even sure where to even start for this. Tried looking into CSV parsing, removing duplicates (thinking there may be something I can manipulate to do this), and I've even looked into PyMongo to do this but that got complex fast haha. I really appreciate the feedback I've gotten here, I'll be much more specific in my next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is a good fit for this, here's how you can use it to do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd 

# load the csv data into a dataframe 
df = pd.read_csv("link_to_csv_file", sep=",")
# group everything using the  "businesses" column 
df = df.groupby("businesses", as_index=False).head(5) 
# write the results back to a csv file
df.to_csv("cleaned_csv_file.csv", sep=",", index=False)
```

You can install pandas as follows:

```
pip install pandas
```

### Example:

Here's a reproducible example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> f = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4],'value':[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,1], 'business': ["google", "google", "IBM", "Microsoft", "google","IBM", "google", "IBM","Microsoft" ]})
>>> f
    business  id  value
0     google   1      1
1     google   1      2
2        IBM   1      3
3  Microsoft   2      1
4     google   2      2
5        IBM   2      3
6     google   2      4
7        IBM   3      1
8  Microsoft   4      1
>>> f.groupby("business",as_index=False).head(2)
    business  id  value
0     google   1      1
1     google   1      2
2        IBM   1      3
3  Microsoft   2      1
5        IBM   2      3
8  Microsoft   4      1
>>> f.groupby("business",as_index=False).head(2)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Do you have any recommendation as to how I can take the next 5 duplicates (if there are more duplicates) and put them into a new csv? Some of these companies have around 20-50 contacts so if there was 20 I'd want them into 4 seperate files with 5 in each. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @ClaytonStewart This seems to me a different question, that needs a bit of thinking, I guess you'd do better if you create a new question for it. If the current answer is sufficient for your initial question, consider accepting it.